# How to avoid deselecting text on Winforms TextBox when clicking on selected text?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drag-and-drop

I would like to implement a drag&drop operation from `TextBox` to another control.
The problem is that when you select some part of text and then click on the `TextBox` text is deselected. Therefore when I perform `DoDragDrop` in `MouseDown` event the `textBox.SelectedText` is already empty.

Is there any way to avoid such behavior? I found following [example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0460__GUI-Windows-Forms/DragandDropTextBox.htm) but I don't want to loose the possibility to drag&drop only a part of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution. You need to inherit TextBox and override OnMouseDown and WndProc:

```
public class DragTextBox : TextBox
{
    private string dragText;
    private const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201;

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dragText.Length > 0)
        {
            SelectionStart = Text.IndexOf(dragText);
            SelectionLength = dragText.Length;
            DoDragDrop(dragText, DragDropEffects.Copy);
            SelectionLength = 0;
        }
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if ((m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN))
            dragText = SelectedText;
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Original code author post [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/10c419f6-d797-4c85-b8d5-a83bb61e1d2a)